# Why does C++11 allow for GC?

Tags: c++, c++11, garbage-collection

C++11 allows its implementations to perform (some) garbage collection utilities. Why would the standard allow this? I was always under the impression that in C++, you don't pay for what you don't use. To me, (implicit) GC feels like it undermines this ideology. In addition, it's not hard to write and use an explicit garbage collection utility in C++ via smart-pointers.

Second, GC will make some otherwise valid programs invalid. Examples include pointer masking and related low-level pointer "hacks".

```
int * nums = new int[10];
nums += 2;
*nums = 777; // nothing points to the new'ed int[10] at this point
// oh no! nums could have gotten collected!!! (so lets assume it was)
*nums = 666; // crash (or memory corruption (or something else that's bad))
```

Comment: If a garbage collector gets the option to release the memory used for the `Foo` object, that does not mean it must first call `Foo`'s destructor.

Comment: @hvd: Right. I've updated my question

Comment: Pointer masking and other such "low level pointer hacks" are not supported by the language; those are implementation-dependent already.

Comment: C++ doesn't allow implementations to just perform random garbage collection. Rather, it provides a standardized *interface* for specific, *new* functionality that provides garbage-collected memory.

Comment: @JamesMcNellis A xor-list for pointer values stored as integers was previously perfectly valid.

Comment: @hvd Well, the conversions between integers and pointers are implementation dependent, but it's true that if the implementation is such that the xor trick yields the expected value then using that value as a pointer is valid in C++03. Now with a C++11 implementation that has strict pointer safety you'd have to use `std::declare_reachable()` to make such code valid. In implementations with relaxed safety that trick is still valid.

Comment: http://herbsutter.com/2011/10/25/garbage-collection-synopsis-and-c/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The GC is not required to exist by the C++11 standard, but it might be in the future versions.

It is not going to be enforced on you - it will be there only if you request it. It will not collect your normal pointers, it will not collect the current smart pointers. So, it is still the 'don't use - don't pay for it'. It will work only on the pointers you explicitly ask it to, so your example will still work as it does now.

See [Sutter’s Mill: Garbage Collection Synopsis, and C++](http://herbsutter.com/2011/10/25/garbage-collection-synopsis-and-c/)

> Reference counting (#1) is often the best and it’s C++’s default
>   form of GC. But there are reasons to also (not instead) want lazy
>   mark-sweep (#2) garbage collection in C++ to deal with things ref
>   counting can’t deal with, including when potential cycles are
>   unavoidable (in some cases some objects may naturally be shared,
>   but then might refer to each other) and lock-free ABA issues.

By "reference counting", Sutter is refering to `std::shared_ptr` and similar things.